# Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Prove that $1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +...+ (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv p + (p-1)! \mod p^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Prove that
> $$1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +...+ (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv p + (p-1)! \mod p^2$$

I was going through this post https://mathoverflow.net/a/319824/168814.
And I couldn't follow how
\begin{align}(ab)^{p-1}-1=&b^{p-1}(a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1)
\\\equiv& (a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1)\pmod {p^2}.\end{align}

I did understand that $(ab)^{p-1}-1=b^{p-1}(a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1).$ But how did we get$ b^{p-1}(a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1)
\equiv (a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1)\pmod {p^2}?$ This is true for $\mod p$ but I am not sure about $\mod p^2.$

Also can anyone direct me to an elementary proof?

I got this true in mod p.
$$1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +...+ (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv p + (p-1)! \mod p$$

We just use fermat's and Wilson here. As $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p.$ And $(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p.$

Comment: hello, i am trying a problem in which i am trying to look at the exact thing mod p^3, do you know what this is mod p^3?

Comment: @Aditya_math hey! I am not sure because mod p^3 is hard to handle..You can edit this question or make a new question, if you are interested!

Comment: @above , ah, i just realised that my method for solving that question (2001 ISL N4 i think, the one about a^{p-1}-1 was completely undoable. so i just wasted a lot of my time lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p$. Thus, the part of $b^{p-1}$ which is divisible by $p$ can be ignored, since the product will be divisible by $p^2$. Once again, by Fermat's Little Theorem, you get:
$$b^{p-1}(a^{p-1}-1) \equiv 1 \cdot (a^{p-1}-1) \equiv a^{p-1}-1 \pmod{p^2}$$

Comment: Thankyou! I got it..